# Flafka: Kafka to Flume agent HDFS not ingesting

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-kafka, flume, kafka-consumer-api

I am creating a Flume agent that ingests data from a Kafka topic, the channel is a Kafka topic, and the sink is HDFS. The agent is supposed to take the take data from the kafka topic and land it in a daily folder in hdfs. I am on a cloudera distribution. It is currently not ingesting the data. No error message was given, the data is populating the topic successfully.

```
sandbox.sources = kafka
sandbox.channels= channel
sandbox.sinks=sink_to_hdfs

#source configuration
sandbox.sources.kafka.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
sandbox.sources.kafka.zookeeperConnect = zookeeper_address:2181/kafka
sandbox.sources.kafka.topic= topic
sandbox.sources.kafka.groupId= flume
sandbox.sources.kafka.channels=channel


#channel configuration
sandbox.channels.channel.type=org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
sandbox.channels.channel.brokerList=kafkabroker_server:9092 
sandbox.channels.channel.topic=kafka-channel-01
sandbox.channels.channel.zookeeperConnect = zookeeper_address:2181/kafka


#sink configuration
sandbox.sinks.sink_to_hdfs.channel= channel
sandbox.sinks.sink_to_hdfs.type=hdfs
sandbox.sinks.sink_to_hdfs.writeFormat=Text
sandbox.sinks.sink_to_hdfs.hdfs.fileType= DataStream
sandbox.sinks.sink_to_hdfs.hdfs.path=/user/myname/flume/%{topic}/%Y-%m-%d

sandbox.sinks.sink_to_hdfs.hdfs.rollInterval=10 
sandbox.sinks.sink_to_hdfs.hdfs.rollSize=8000000
sandbox.sinks.sink_to_hdfs.hdfs.rollCount=0
sandbox.sinks.sink_to_hdfs.hdfs.idleTimeout=3600

#channel capacity
sandbox.channels.channel.transactionCapacity = 1000
sandbox.channels.channel.capacity= 10000
```

Comment: How do you know your setup is not working? Can you please paste some of your logs? (Especially things that could be related to HDFS)

Comment: As Bessbd mentioned, the list of things that could possibly be wrong is infinite - ZK is down, Kafka is down, HDFS is down, Flume is down, you have no permissions to read, no permissions to write, etc, etc. Logs, please.